# Digital signals in RF PCB

Tags: rf, filter, digital-control

I'm working on a RF 4 layer PCB that includes RF switch ([PE426412](https://www.psemi.com/pdf/datasheets/pe426412ds.pdf)). This Ic is controlled by 4 digital pins.These digital signals differentially come from out of the board and by [ADM485ARZ](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM485.pdf) converts to a single.
I don't know if my circuit needs further filters or any other thing that I should be concern about.
[image]
Thank you to help me find the answers.

Comment: why the strange, non-rectangular layout when you, in the end, just add rotation-symmetric SMA connectors? Why do the U9,U10… need to rotated? Why the decoupling caps, too? Assuming e.g. C18 belongs to U15, why add vias to some signal layer and back to top if you could have just placed a mm of trace on top? That's reducing the efficiency of your decoupling caps significantly! You're not only gaining nothing by having them rotated, you're also making this unnecessarily much of a nightmare to assemble. Your power traces should, if possible, also be a bit wider.

Comment: What frequencies is this operating at? I assume your striplines are curved to length-match them. How long is the wavelength at the operational frequencies?

Comment: is this your (or your organisation's) design, or is it an evaluation board from the switch manufacturer to demo the switch? I'd like to see resistors like R16,17 right up at the switch package

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for your answer friend. I'm a beginner designer so I need help to improve my skills. The operating frequency is 3GHz so the wavelength equals 10cm. Exactly I place SMAs and bias-tees because of length matching . Actually C18 and ... are needed as the datasheet of bias-tee said. I was wondering I should add a ferrite bead in the way of single digital signals.

Comment: Can you mount the connectors on the opposite side of the board?

Comment: Some of your vias are too close to the RF traces at some places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, you have diff '485 into the board, with the output of the diff receiver feeding the RF switch?

The data sheet for the Peregrine RF switch doesn't state what the control lines feed into.  But it must be a CMOS gate of some sort because of the low 10 uA max input current.

Our microwave devices like this usually contain an RC filter on the control inputs, something like a 4.7K resistor and a 10 pf cap to ground.  If you're concerned about digital noise coupling onto the RF through the switch, then it might be worthwhile considering something like this.  This would cause the switching to slow down a bit, and is something you would have to evaluate.

Note than unless you have a tight group delay and/or phase matching requirement between the channels, there is no need to have the circular layout you showed.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I can't add a comment (< 50 rep) anyways, to optimize further, place the SMA's on the opposite side of the board, you are effectively smashing the wave into metal, and causing mismatch.

Take a look at.
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.399.4140&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'v read that document. It has a very good information but finaly I didn't know why do you say I should place SMAs on the bottom layer?